# Where can i get the Avro code example?

Tags: avro

The documentation at http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/gettingstartedjava.html#download_install stipulates that there is an example "in the Avro docs". Unjaring pretty much everything, i am not finding any examples/ directory. 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the [repo](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/avro/trunk/doc/examples/java-example/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - it was *not* in the language specific jars, it was outside/along side of them.
See http://apache.tradebit.com/pub/avro/avro-1.7.7/  for example.